# How do I select fields from an existing Rails resource, not from database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an existing model object, I want to "slim it down" to just a few fields. Use cases include receiving an item from one service to be filtered before passing it on to another service, or using fixtures in tests.

The following works on the database query:

```
User.select([:firstname,:lastname]).first
```

to get the record with only `firstname` and `lastname`. What if I already did `u = User.first` so I now have `u` which has *all* of the fields.

How do I turn `u` into an object with just the two fields above without making another inefficient DB query?

```
u.select([:firstname,:lastname])
```

doesn't work.

To clarify: I want to get to the equivalent of `User.select(:firstname,:lastname).first` if I already have the output (post-SQL) of `User.first`. What is my next step?

Comment: You shouldn't most of the time. Where do you intend on passing the retrieved objects to? Does it have a filtering parameter?

Comment: I first stumbled across the problem in testing. I have a fixtures `users(:james)` which is the entire object, but I want to make sure that it passes just the 2 allowed fields (no email or password). Then I came across it in another context.

Comment: "filtering parameter"?

Comment: To be fair, I probably could get away with the service problem in other ways, but the tests are still important. `assert_equal users(:james), assigns(:users)` will fail, because `assigns(:users)` only has the 2 fields, while `users(:james)` has everything.

Comment: Where do you need to pass that object?

Comment: Are you looking for `User.first.pluck(:f_name, :l_name)` ?

Comment: @R_O_R nope, that makes a query.

Comment: @D-side exactly. I already have an object, just trying to get it to lose some weight. :-)

Comment: I haven't worked with fixtures much. Does `users(:james)` have an id? What does it return?

Comment: Yeah, it loads it up in the DB and then creates a quick link. Very useful.

Comment: AFAIK regardless of the fieldsets, two objects are considered equal "by value" (`==`) if they have equal `id`s. ActiveRecord's rule. So if they both have equal `id`s, that should work.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. Could be because I retrieve *only* `:firstname, :lastname` and not ID....

Comment: In any case, for the testing, I actually *want* to test that it populates only the right fields.

Comment: `id` is object's identity in RDBMS. You can't reliably compare two objects from the database if any one of them doesn't have an `id`. You could compare actual field values, one by one, but that would also match a different object with the same field values. Is that your desired behavior?

Comment: I guess I am doing both: I need to check which objects they returned, and that they only populated the given fields

Comment: You can't reliably determine the identity of the object that does not have an `id`. So either you add `id`, or you compare by values.

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question as it is not clear what you are trying to do... Some code might help too

Comment: If you want to test that an object only has those two fields, why are you starting out with a full object?

Comment: @MaxWilliams Because the controller fetches it using `.select()`, which is good. But my tests need to ensure that it properly used `.select()` otherwise it could pass through unsafe or private fields.

Comment: So why not just test if it responds to one (or all) of the other fields, and then you will know whether it was created with .select() or not?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I thought about that, but then I risk missing fields. Much better to test "do you have only fields A & B" than "do you not have fields C & D & E & F &...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It doesn't work that way.

The essence of [Active Record pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) (at heart of Rails' ActiveRecord) is that each object corresponds to a specific row in the database. Not backwards though: there may be multiple objects that point to the same row. That's causing some trouble here.

#### You can either have identity comparison...

In RDBMS the only way you can make sure the two objects correspond to the same row is to compare the objects' primary keys. If one of the two objects doesn't have a primary key, you don't hav a way to determine if whether they are one and the same row.

> But ActiveRecord does something, right?

Nothing fancy, actually:

```
def ==(comparison_object)
  super || # If it's one and the same Ruby object, the result is obvious
    comparison_object.instance_of?(self.class) && # otherwise if same class
    !id.nil? && # and there IS non-nil id
    comparison_object.id == id # Then compare their ids
end
```

So if the object doesn't have an `id`, it's non-equal to anything but itself.

#### ...or you can do comparison by value

That takes you about as far as comparing field-by-field, no different than comparing hashes of attributes.

This has a downside that the condition would pass even if the object is built from a different row, but contains the same values in given attributes. I woudn't regard that as a problem: in that specific case **you know where one of the compared objects originates** (a fixture, I suppose), so **its data is trusted**. So if the given object contains the same data that the trusted object has, the test is reliable enough.

For that you could one object's entire hash of attributes and compare it to a slice of your fixture:

```
assert_equal a.attributes, b.attributes.slice(:key1, :key2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [attributes hash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes) for this.

```
user = User.find(187287)
user.attributes.slice("first_name", "last_name")
{
    "first_name" => "Jacob",
     "last_name" => "Elder"
}
```

Note that Hash#slice is a method added by Rails. It is not part of Ruby's builtin Hash class.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice

Comment: Well, one doesn't have to use Rails in its entirety to do this. [Core Extenstions of ActiveSupport are enough](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Slice).

Comment: I do like that. I end up with a hash, not the object, but I could compare the attributes of one to the attributes.slice of the other. Not exactly an answer - gives hash, not the object - but definitely an upvote!

Comment: Hash implements a helpful equality operator, too. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html#method-i-3D-3D

Even if you could get two ActiveRecord objects with just the attributes you want, it wouldn't change the equality operator's behavior. There, equality depends only on the underlying row's primary key.

Comment: @jelder ...or on object identity, if there is no `id`, such as in new records or after specific queries, like in the question.